# Color nodes of a graph created with igraph proportionally to eigenvector centrality of that node

Tags: r, igraph

I am using the library `igraph` in `R`. I have created an MST graph by using the function mst based on some distance function stored in a dataframe called `tree`:

```
gf <- graph_from_data_frame(tree, directed = FALSE)
mstgf <- mst(gf, weights = tree$distance)
```

I have calculated the eigenvector centrality of each node in the MST as:

```
ec <- eigen_centrality(mstgf, directed=T, weights=NA)$vector
```

I have then joined the vector of eigenvector centralities to the data.frame tree:

```
x <- cbind(names(ec), as.numeric(ec)) %>% as_tibble() %>% mutate(V2 = as.numeric(V2)) %>% 
        rename(from = V1) 
        
tree <- tree %>% inner_join(.,x, by = "from")
```

What I want to do is to plot the MST by coloring the nodes in a way to resemble their eigenvector centrality. I am using the following for plotting, yet I don't know how to change the argument `vertex.color` to obtain something like the image below?

```
plot.igraph(mstgf,
                vertex.color =  round(tree$V2,0),   
                edge.color = "blue", 
                edge.curved = TRUE,  
                edge.witdh = 1,      
    )
```

[image]

Comment: May be something like this: `vertex.color =  topo.colors(length(tree$V2))[order(tree$V2)]`

Answer (score 0):

Once you've calculated the centralities of your choice, you would like to 1) scale the values to a meaningful categorical range (like 1,2,3,4,5) and 2) associate your centrality categories with colors from a gradient. You don't necessarily have to keep joining and calculating outside igraph.

This is a random network

```
# Random network
g <- erdos.renyi.game(100,250,'gnm', directed=F)
```

**1) make categories**

This forces every eigenvector centrality to assume an integer value between 1 and 10

```
# Calculate eigen centrality and check the distribution We're attaching the
# result of eigen_centrality() straight onto the vertices as verticy-attributes
V(g)$ec <- eigen_centrality(g, directed=T, weights=NA)$vector
hist(V(g)$ec)

# You could use the scales package, or define this normalisation function:
normalize <- function(x){(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))}
(V(g)$ec_index <- round(normalize(V(g)$ec) * 9) + 1)
#ec_index should now be a category between 1 and 10 for your centralities
```

You can use any resolution you like.

**2) Attach colours from the indexation**

There are several packages and ways to load colour-ranges in R (colorspace, colorRamps, RColorBrewer etc).

```
# Build a color-mapping with 10 categories and set the color of each
# node to the corresponding color of each centrality-measure category
V(g)$color <- colorRampPalette(c("turquoise", "yellow","red"))(10)[V(g)$ec_index]

# Look at what we did
table(V(g)$color)
plot(g, vertex.label=NA, vertex.size=5)
```

This example should produce something along the lines of this graph here:

[image]